# Undefined variable + Cannot access empty property

Tags: php

Im writing a class with a somewhat primitive way of errorlogging. It is using an array as property called "action" in which it records it's last performed action. However, it doesn't work. Everytime I try to store something I get the following errors both on the same line:

1. Notice: Undefined variable: action
2. Fatal error: Cannot access empty property

From bottom to top, the field is defined as:

```
class Foo
{
    ...

    public $action = array();

    ...
```

Reset after every action by:

```
private function update() {

    ...

    unset($this->action);
    $this->action = array();
}
```

And set following the format (this is done at multiple places and all return the same error):

```
$this->update();
array_push( $this->$action, "Bar");
```

I also noticed this always happens at the first step, so Im suspecting a syntax error, but have no clue where exactly.

Can anyone of you identify the problem?

Comment: `$this->$action` -> `$this->action` one dollar sign too much .

Comment: `$this->$action` is effectively equivalent to `$this->{""}` (ie. "empty property of this") because `$action` is undefined - you're accidentally using a variable property.

Comment: Ouch, and I was thinking I checked that :-/ That solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invalid variable reference at the line:

```
array_push( $this->$action, "Bar");
```

use:

```
$var->property_of_var
array_push( $this->action, "Bar");
```